# Counting palindrome words

Tags: c++

I am given a text and I am required to count how many palindrome words it has. No matter how many palindromes I type in it always returns 1. My attempt :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
char s[255],*p,aux[20];
int n,c,k;
int main()
{
cin.get(s,255);cin.get();
p=strtok(s," ?.,;");
while(p)
{
    for(int i=strlen(p)-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        aux[k]=p[i];
        k++;
    }
    if(strcmp(aux,p)==0)c++;
    p=strtok(NULL," ?.,;");
}
cout<<c;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: There multiple bugs in the shown code. Lack of bounds checking. A word with more than 20 characters results in an array overflow and undefined behavior. You're also forgetting that  plain old C strings are null-terminated, and your reversed string is not null-terminated, which is also undefined behavior. Finally, if your intentions are to code in C++, and not in C, you should be using `std::string` instead of error-prone, fixed length `char` buffers. `char` buffers are so ...last century.

Comment: This is what I am learning in school : C++ with mostly C functions. I know it is not the best way to do it, but this this is what I am taught.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that your real problem is an incompetent instructor, who's claiming to teach you C++, but instead teaches you ancient C. There's no good answer here except to try to find a different instructor to learn C++ from. This is not modern C++, and writing code like this won't help you, if you expect to become a professional C++ programmer.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but this is the national curriculum here. I am a high school student and this kind of "C++" is expected from everyone here ,so regardless of its uselessness I still have to solve it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Initial k=0 before for loop, counter c=0 and use end of string terminator '\0'.

```
char s[255], *p,  aux[20];
cin.get(s, 255); cin.get();
p = strtok(s, " ?.,;");
vector<string> words;
int c = 0,k;
while (p)
{
    k = 0; // see here
    for (int i = strlen(p) - 1; i >= 0; i--,k++)
    {
        aux[k] = p[i];
    }
    aux[k] = '\0'; // and here
    if (strcmp(aux, p) == 0)c++;
    p = strtok(NULL, " ?.,;");
}
cout << c << '\n';
```

As advised by Sam Varshavchik, avoid using char*, use std::string and std::stringstream. Using std::string the palindrome evaluation could have being accomplished using a one liner code like this:

```
while (p)
{
    string str(p);
    if (str == string(str.rbegin(), str.rend())) {
        c++;
    }
    p = strtok(NULL, " ?.,;");
}
```